# In R, I want to calculate percentages of a total, but the totals are in rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

ZipCode    AGIBand    NumReturns
94022    Total               9530
94022    under25         1850
94022    25to500         890
94022    50to75           730
94022    75to100         570
94022    100to200       1690
94022    over200         3800
94024    Total         10790
94024    under25         2170
94024    25to500         900
94024    50to75         820
94024    75to100         650
94024    100to200         1970
94024    over200         4280

(sorry for the formatting -- I'm new here)

I'd like to add a column that has % of total for each zip code. For example:

94022 | under 25 | 1850 | percent of total = 1850/9530

How can I do that in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in the dataframe 'dat':

```
zipCodes <- unique(dat$ZipCode)
totalRows <- dat$AGIBand == "Total"

for (z in zipCodes){
  zipRows <- (dat$ZipCode == z)
  zipTotalRow <- totalRows & zipRows
  zipTotal <- dat$NumReturns[zipTotalRow]
  dat$Percentage[zipRows] <- dat$NumReturns[zipRows] / zipTotal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ZipCode', we divide the 'NumReturns' with 'NumReturns' corresponding to `Total` in 'AGIBand' and assign (`:=`) it as new column 'Perc'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Perc := 100*(NumReturns/NumReturns[AGIBand=="Total"]) , by = ZipCode]
df1
#  ZipCode  AGIBand NumReturns       Perc
# 1:   94022    Total       9530 100.000000
# 2:   94022  under25       1850  19.412382
# 3:   94022  25to500        890   9.338930
# 4:   94022   50to75        730   7.660021
# 5:   94022  75to100        570   5.981112
# 6:   94022 100to200       1690  17.733473
# 7:   94022  over200       3800  39.874082
# 8:   94024    Total      10790 100.000000
# 9:   94024  under25       2170  20.111214
#10:   94024  25to500        900   8.341057
#11:   94024   50to75        820   7.599629
#12:   94024  75to100        650   6.024096
#13:   94024 100to200       1970  18.257646
#14:   94024  over200       4280  39.666358
```